# How do I use more "select query" with Mysql to get result from different table

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I've 3 database table.

1) users
2) user_property
3) offers

**users table structure:**

```
----------------------------------    
id    pc1   pc2    pc3      pc4
----------------------------------
1     1205  1203   1208    1209
2     1206  1205   1209    1202
3     1207  1204   1210    1201
4     1208  1210   1211    1203
5     1209  1207   1208    1204
```

**user_property table structure:**

```
----------------------------------------------------    
property_id    user_id   postcode    creation_date
----------------------------------------------------
1              1         1205       02-01-2001
2              2         1206       02-03-2001
3              3         1207       02-04-2001
4              4         1205       02-05-2001
5              5         1208       02-06-2001
6              4         1205       02-07-2001
```

**offers table structure:**

```
-------------------------
offer_id      property_id
-------------------------
1              1         
2              2         
3              3         
4              4         
5              5         
6              4
```

**Query**

```
$myQuery =  mysql_query("
 SELECT * 
   FROM user_property upr 
  WHERE (postcode = '$pc1' OR
         postcode = '$pc2' OR
         postcode = '$pc3' OR
         postcode = '$pc4') AND
         datediff(CURDATE(), upr.creation_date) <= 7 AND
         NOT EXISTS(SELECT ofr.property_id 
                      FROM offers ofr 
                     WHERE ofr.property_id = upr.property_id AND
                           ofr.agent_id IN(SELECT id 
                                             FROM users 
                                            WHERE company_name !=''
                                          )
                   )
ORDER BY property_id DESC");
```

in this `$myQuery` query you can see that `( postcode = '$pc1' or postcode = '$pc2' or postcode = '$pc3' or postcode = '$pc4' )` . this postcode is come from `users` table.

**So how can i to get those postcode with 1 sql query from `user_property` table ?**

you also see that I just get id by using `IN (select id from users where company_name !='')`. If i use same query to get those postcode then it's not working. May be something I mistake.

Comment: since you haven't provided the structure of two of your three tables, much less explained WHAT this query is supposed to be accomplishing, we can't help you.

Comment: Ok March B I'm editing my question.

Comment: while you're at it, might you consider adding some newlines into the Query code so we can see the code without scrolling? :)

Comment: @MarcB please see my question.

Comment: Thanks for editing.  I'm still not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  You say you're tring to get "those postcode" but you're specifying 4 different postcodes, so any of your results will have one of those four.  Are you trying to see if any results from the rest of the query have those 4 post codes?

Comment: @DanFarrell In users account they have 4 postcode. So once a new property is submitted I want to get few details which match user postcode to submitted property postcode.

Comment: @DanFarrell yes you right.

Comment: ah, I think I understand. It's confusing because you say `SELECT *` so  it's hard to see what exactly the query is looking to find - but you're trying to find results from user, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48828/discussion-between-dan-farrell-and-babu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from our discussion we ended up with:

```
select 
  users.*, 
  user_property.*, 
  offers.property_id as offers_property_id 
from users 
  join user_property on users.id = user_property.user_id
    and (
          user_property.postcode = users.pc1 
      or  user_property.postcode = users.pc2
      or  user_property.postcode = users.pc3
      or  user_property.postcode = users.pc4
    )
  left join offers on 
    offers.property_id = user_property.property_id
    and offers.agent_id = users.id 

where users.company_name != ""
  and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), user_property.creation_date) <= 7

HAVING offers_property_id IS NULL;
```